# Why doesn't decompression maintain quality?

Tags: graphics

I have read that for reading a compressed image into memory it must be decompressed first and the original size will be allocated. So, since it is decompressed and it's size before compression is allocated in memory, why is the resolution of a compressed image when viewed with a certain software not the same of the original one?

Comment: "*why is the resolution of a compressed image when viewed with a certain software not the same of the original one*"... where did you observe that behavior? Also, this question isn't really related to game-development.

Answer (score 6):

Compression is not about reducing the resolution, or size in pixels, of an image. Compression is about reducing the amount of bytes required to represent a specific image.

You can see an image as an array of 4-byte structures, one for each pixel, where each byte represents one of the components of the color of each pixel, namely red, green, blue and alpha. The size required to represent an image with this scheme is

```
width * height * 4
```

So a 100x100 pixel image would have 10000 pixels, and therefore consume 40000 bytes. This is in fact, roughly the way in which the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) format stores images.

However, this is not the only way you can represent those 10000 pixels. If, for example, the first 5000 pixels are blue, and the bottom pixels are brown, you could represent the image by saying something like "blue: 5000, brown 5000", and that would take much fewer bytes to represent. This scheme is roughly how RLE ([Run Length Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)) works, and is widely used in many formats such as [GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format).

However, there is only so much you can do to reduce the amount of bytes required to represent the bytes in your image. The data is not always easy to represent with fewer bytes, so what some compression algorithms, like the one used in [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) files do, is to modify the pixels just a bit, so the data is much easier to compress, yet the changes are not very noticeable. If such changes are acceptable, it is possible to achieve impressive results when compressing the image. This is what is called "lossy compression".

The entire point of compressing images is to make it easier to move images from one place to another, be it by storing them on a disc or sending them over the internet. However, when you are going to display an image, your computer has to tell the monitor what color each pixel has to get, so once you are going to display the image, you need to decompress it.

Comment: Also note that lossy compression is the only way to force a given compression rate (e.g. "Make my image smaller than 100KiB at any cost").

Answer (score 2):

Technically, *de*compressing a compressed image does maintain the quality of the compressed image. However *compressing* an image may reduce quality (ie. the compressed image is slightly degraded from the original image).

The specific changes to the image depend on what sort of compression you apply; that said, I'm not familiar with any sort of compression that would change the resolution or size of the image. Are you sure you got that right?

Comment: "...I'm not familiar with any sort of compression that would change the resolution or size of the image".. So why is compression used?

Comment: To reduce the filesize of the image. What's compressed is the file size, not the image size.